# Como verificar se algum registro foi retornado, a quantidade deles e se algum registro foi alterado em uma query com PDO e MySQL?

Tags: php, pdo

Após realizar uma query (Um INSERT ou UPDATE) gostaria de saber se foi feita alguma alteração no banco de dados ou se nada aconteceu. Com Mysqli eu utilizava o mysqli_affected_rows. Porém não sei como eu faria isso com o PDO. Em um SELECT eu gostaria de saber se foi retornado algum registros e quantos registros foram encontrados.

Exemplos de código que eu gostaria de ter uma informação se houve alterações:

**INSERT:**

Gostaria de saber se os registros foram inseridos

```html
<?php

//Conexão com o Banco de Dados 
$c = new Conexao();
$conexao = $c->conectar();
        
$query = "INSERT INTO events(title,color,start,end)VALUES(:titulo_evento,:cor_evento,:inicio_evento,:fim_evento)";

$stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);    

$stmt->bindValue(':titulo_evento',$this->__get('titulo_evento'));

$stmt->bindValue(':cor_evento',$this->__get('cor_evento'));

$stmt->bindValue(':inicio_evento',$this->__get('inicio_evento'));

$stmt->bindValue(':fim_evento',$this->__get('fim_evento'));

$stmt->execute();

//Aqui eu gostaria de verificar se o Insert deu certo

?>
```

**UPDATE**

Gostaria de saber se os registros foram atualizados corretamente

```html
<?php

//Conexão com o Banco de Dados 
$c = new Conexao();
$conexao = $c->conectar();
        
$query = "UPDATE events SET title = :titulo_evento, color = :cor_evento, start = :inicio_evento, end = :fim_evento WHERE id = :id" 
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);    

$stmt->bindValue(':titulo_evento',$this->__get('titulo_evento'));                            
$stmt->bindValue(':cor_evento',$this->__get('cor_evento'));
$stmt->bindValue(':inicio_evento',$this->__get('inicio_evento'));
$stmt->bindValue(':fim_evento',$this->__get('fim_evento'));
$stmt->bindValue(':id',$this->__get('id'));

$stmt->execute();

//Aqui eu gostaria de verificar se o Update deu certo (Por exemplo, alterou a linha)

?>
```

**SELECT:**

Gostaria de saber se foi encontrado algum registro e quantos foram

```html
<?php

//Conexão com o Banco de Dados 
$c = new Conexao();
$conexao = $c->conectar();
        
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE idade = :idade";

$stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);    

$stmt->bindValue(':idade',$this->__get('idade'));

$stmt->execute();

//Aqui eu gostaria de verificar se o SELECT encontrou algum registro e quantos registros ele encontrou

?>
```

Comment: Já viu o [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php)?

Comment: Não, sou meio novo no PDO. Esse rowCount retorna o número de linhas afetadas ? Poderia ser utilizado no Select e no Update ?

Comment: O `$stmt->execute()` te retorna um boolean. Você pode determinar se funcionou ou não com o retorno dessa função. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php